# JDBC MYSQL ORDER BY works in MYSQL Workbench but not java application

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am building a small console application to help me manage my finances. Currently I am just querying all the data in my MYSQL database but I wanted the purchases stored to be displayed from newest date to latest date.

When I run the query in workbench I get the desired output. I Litterally copied and pasted the query string into my java application but the ORDER BY clause does not seem to get compiled. Suggestions?

The desired output from mysql which works

[image: MYSQL Workbench query and output]

The code that I use for the query

[image: Java method that queries DB]

```
    // code used to call getItems within switch in another class.
    switch (userMenuChoice) {
            case 1:
                ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(db.getItems());
                displayItems(items);
                break; // there are more case statements but not included here

    // method to display all the items from query result set
    public static void displayItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    Collections.sort(items);
    for(Item item:items) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Date: %-15s", item.getSaleDate())
                + String.format("Store: %-15s", item.getStore())
                + String.format("Type: %-15s", item.getItemType())
                + String.format("Cost: %-10s", item.getItemPrice()));
    }
}
```

The not desired output. Ignores the ORDER BY clause for some reason

[image]

Comment: Please **don't** post code as image. Paste your code as text using the code tool inside the editor. Also, please post the code which calls `getItems()` and prints the received data.

Comment: Posting images of code and errors is frowned upon here, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, we need to understand how your output is generated, as we cannot rule out the problem being there.

Comment: I am new to posting in stack. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Collections.sort() call from your displayItems method, that should fix it.

Comment: Wow good catch! This was old code before I used MYSQL and only JDBC without ordering. Didn't realize this was still there. Thank you so much.